# Python/ttk/tKinter - getting the value of a Checkbox

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Following the TkDocs Tutorial (http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#checkbutton) I am trying to set up a check box, but I can't follow exactly what I should be doing to 'get' the toggled value.

```
    self.valAStatus = StringVar()
    self.checkA = ttk.Checkbutton(self.mainframe, text='A', command = lambda: self.getStatus(self.boxA, "A"),variable=self.valAStatus, onvalue='letter', offvalue='colour')
```

and

```
def getStatus(self, boxRef, value):
    boxRef.insert(1, value)
```

What I'm not sure on is how to get the either `onvalue` or `offvalue` from the `self.checkA` object

I'm not sure if I am looking at the StringVar `self.valAStatus`
(that results in `PY_VAR0` and has no attribute `onvalue`) or if I should be looking at the `self.checkA` object (that results in `.40972728.40972656.40972800.41009024` and has no attribute `onvalue`).

I've probably missed something in the docs, but if anyone could point out what its doing, so I can get the `(on|off)value` I'd be obliged..

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236910/getting-tkinter-check-box-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `self.valAStatus.get()` which returns the value associated to that check box (in this case, `self.valAStatus`).