# Get the input from a Checkbox in python tkinter?

Tags: python, input, checkbox, tkinter

I am trying to use python and tkinter to make a program that run programs that have been selected in a check box.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
def runSelectedItems():
    if checkCmd == 0:
        labelText = Label(text="It worked").pack()
    else:
        labelText = Label(text="Please select an item from the checklist below").pack()

checkBox1 = Checkbutton(mGui, variable=checkCmd, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, text="Command  Prompt").pack()
buttonCmd = Button(mGui, text="Run Checked Items", command=runSelectedItems).pack()
```

That is the code but I don't understand why it doesn't work?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Tkinter Check Box State](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236910/getting-tkinter-check-box-state)

Answer (score 16):

You need to use an `IntVar` for the variable:

```
checkCmd = IntVar()
checkCmd.set(0)
def runSelectedItems():
    if checkCmd.get() == 0:
        labelText = Label(text="It worked").pack()
    else:
        labelText = Label(text="Please select an item from the checklist below").pack()

checkBox1 = Checkbutton(mGui, variable=checkCmd, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, text="Command  Prompt").pack()
buttonCmd = Button(mGui, text="Run Checked Items", command=runSelectedItems).pack()
```

---

In other news, the idiom:

```
widget = TkinterWidget(...).pack()
```

Is not a very good one.  In this case, `widget` will *always be `None`* since that is what is returned by `Widget.pack()`.  In general, you should create your widget and make it aware of the geometry manager in 2 separate steps. e.g.:

```
checkBox1 = Checkbutton(mGui, variable=checkCmd, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, text="Command  Prompt")
checkBox1.pack()
```