# How to get state of Checkbutton when it's selected?

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

How can I get the state of a `Checkbutton` in python? I have this:

```
def doSomething():

  if #code goes here, if checkbutton is selected
   ...

check = Checkbutton(window, text="Add both", onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0)
check.pack(side="right")
```

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236910/getting-checkbutton-state/41081709#41081709

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to associate the `Checkbox` with a variable:

```
is_checked = IntVar()
check = Checkbutton(window, text="Add both", onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=is_checked)
```

Then utilise do your check such as:

```
if is_checked.get():
    # do something
```

Comment: Screwed me up for two hours because this answer was missing `.get()`.

Comment: what if you dont want to create new variable just for checkbox?