# Tkinter get selected value of a CheckButton

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have tried several [examples from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778424/python-if-checkbutton-is-selected), but didn't work for me unfortunately.

I just want to get the value of selected checkButton of Tkinter, Python.

I have a list of CheckButton and its like below

```
## csv file has rows like
# 101, apple
# 102, orange
for row in csvReader:
        checkButton = Checkbutton(top, text = row[1], variable = StringVar(), 
                 onvalue = row[0], offvalue = "0", height=2, \
                 width = 0, justify=Tkinter.LEFT)
        checkButton.pack()
        checkBoxList.append(checkButton)
```

On clicking a button from the form, here is the callback that needs to grab the checked value of checkbox.

```
def btnStartCallBack():
    for chkBox in checkBoxList:
        print chkBox.variable().get()
        # also tried below
        # print chkBox.get()
        # print chkBox.var()
        # print chkBox.onvalue.get()
```

it returns:

```
AttributeError: Checkbutton instance has no attribute 'variable'
```

I just want to know whether it is possible or not to get the value of CheckButton when they are selected. And also at which attribute should I look for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually do my GUIs up in a class, like http://zetcode.com/. I'll do something like

```
self.v = StringVar()
self.cb1 = CheckButton( self, text=row[1], variable=self.v )
```

and then later on..

```
self.v.get()
```

I think that you might need to declare `variable` differently in your code. Bon chasse!

Comment: yes, you are right. its also similar. i have to declare the variable differently. **CheckVar1 = StringVar()** and **Checkvar1.get()** returns the value. Easy... Thanks m8...

Comment: No problem. I remember the first time I learned that stuff--I didn't know I had to use `get()` and it took me hours to figure it out.