# Loop through child widget and store widget values(entry and checkbutton) in list

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I am trying to loop through a child widgets of a frame and store the values of the entry and checkbutton widgets into a list. It seems to work for the entrys but the checkbutton I get an error. If you could help that would be much appreciated thanks.

```
for child in top.winfo_children():        
            if child.winfo_class() == 'Entry':
                mylist.append(child.get())
            elif child.winfo_class() == 'Checkbutton':            
                mylist.append(child.get())
```

I am getting an error here:

```
mylist.append(child.get())
```

The error is :

```
    mylist.append(child.get())
AttributeError: 'Checkbutton' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: You need to use `variable.get()`.

Comment: You need to associate each `Checkbutton` to its own tkinter variable (`StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc) and use its variable to get the checkbutton checked state.

Comment: how would i do that if I am creating a row full of checkbuttons on the fly with for loop?

Comment: the check buttons look like "Checkbutton(frame, text="").grid(row=j, column=k)"

Comment: See here for similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147326/tkinter-get-selected-value-of-a-checkbutton

Comment: @inexp ***how would i do that .. checkbuttons ... with for loop?***: Follow this approach [Correctly extend a tkinter widget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60322108/7414759) extend will a `get()` method.

Comment: thanks for the help! I managed to get it to work