# Tkinter or ttk GUI programming?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, ttk

I'm a beginner in python programming and have to make a project that has to be submitted in school. I discovered tkinter and ttk a month ago and am wondering which one would be better to code.

The purpose of my program is for it to be user-interactive and look as modern as possible. I would appreciate it if you could tell me the advantages of tkinter over ttk and vice versa and which one you recommend I should use.

The program purpose is to interact with the resident of a place and allow him to access different features of the place and stuff like that.

Comment: I think this was closed for the wrong reason. There's no opinion involved in my answer -- it's a fact that you can't use ttk without tkinter.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the difference between the widgets of tkinter and tkinter.ttk in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19561727/3357935)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use ttk without tkinter.

Tkinter is a foundation upon which ttk builds. ttk is a reimplementation of many of the core widgets to have a more modern look. ttk widgets will look nicer, at the expense of customization. For example, a tkinter button's background can be changed, but changing the background of a ttk button is either very difficult or impossible.

Comment: Thanks :).... What would be the advantage of using a ttk Frame over a tkinter root window? What additional features would it give me? And also what deficits? I'm assuming (as a corollary to your above statement) that the ttk mainframe background would also be difficult to change yes?

Comment: @LeroyJD: there is no advantage of a ttk frame over a root window --  you must have a tkinter root window, there is no other option. ttk is part of tkinter, not something separate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight.... I have just one last question.... Is everything that I can do using ttk Styles possible using Tk functions? Thanks again :)