# what is the difference between Label and ttk.Label in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I have a code but After add just Label frame not working fine like that :

```
label = Label(self, text="Test-1")
label .grid(row=1, stick="w", padx=20)
```

The Label not go in Left.

but after add ttk :

```
label = ttk.Label(self, text="Test-1")
label .grid(row=1, stick="w", padx=20)
```

the Label Frame work fine why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what-is-the-difference-between-the-widgets-of-tkinter-and-tkinter-ttk-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561727)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the first one you didn't use this phrase

```
from tkinter import *
```

The `*` imports everything related to tkinter but
if you used this

```
from tkinter import ttk
```

you only import the function that create the table only

Comment: Yeh Thank you for this explaining

Comment: It is worth mentioning that using `from <foo> import *` comes with some [significant downsides](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/7508700)