# How to delete entire row in Tkinter grid layout

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying a test application with Tkinter. I have created a table using grid layout manager as shown below. There are two buttons - *Add row* and *Delete row*. *Add row* works as expected. How i can go about deleting selected rows. My idea was to give a Checkbutton for each row as shown below. And every selected row can be deleted. But  i don't know how to do it exactly and if its possible.

Is there a better way to delete the rows in this case ? please suggest a solution.

[image]

CODE:

```
        from Tkinter import *
        import ttk
        from ttk import * 

        i =2

        def add_row():
            global i 
            var = IntVar()
            c = Checkbutton(root, variable = var)
            c.grid(row = i, column = 0)
            for j in range(1,5): #Columns

                    b = Entry(root)
                    b.grid(row=i, column=j)
            i =i+1 

        root = Tk()
        bt = ttk.Button(root , text = 'Add Row', command = add_row)
        bt.grid(row =0, column=0)


        dl = ttk.Button(root , text = 'Delete Row')
        dl.grid(row =0, column=1)

        v0 = StringVar()
        e0 = Entry(root, textvariable = v0, state = 'readonly')
        v0.set('Select')
        e0.grid(row = 1, column = 0 )

        v1 = StringVar()
        e1 = Entry(root, textvariable = v1, state = 'readonly')
        v1.set('Col1')
        e1.grid(row = 1, column = 1 )

        v2 = StringVar()
        e2 = Entry(root, textvariable = v2, state = 'readonly')
        v2.set('Col2')
        e2.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        v3 = StringVar()
        e3 = Entry(root, textvariable = v3, state = 'readonly')
        v3.set('Col3')
        e3.grid(row = 1, column = 3 )

        v4 = StringVar()
        e4 = Entry(root, textvariable = v4, state = 'readonly')
        v4.set('Col4')
        e4.grid(row = 1, column = 4 )

        mainloop()
```

Note:  I do not want to use tktable or treeview to create tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to delete widgets, you need to keep a reference to them when they are created.

In the code below, I have created a list `rows` which has a sub-list `items` for each row. Each row contains a reference to the checkbutton and all the entries.

When `Delete Row` is pressed, the function loops through the list and destroys all items in the row that has the checkbutton activated, then removes the entry from the list.

**Notes:**

- I have made `var` an attribute of the checkbutton, so that we can access it to see if it has been checked - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236910/getting-tkinter-check-box-state) question.
- You were creating your checkbutton five times for each row; I've taken it out of the loop.
- I [iterate through the list of rows backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/529427/3714940), so that when an item is `pop`-ed, it only changes the index for the rows already processed. This means that you can delete multiple rows at once.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from ttk import * 

i=2
rows = []

def add_row():
    global i 
    i=i+1
    items = []
    var = IntVar()
    c = Checkbutton(root, variable = var)
    c.val = var
    items.append(c)
    c.grid(row = i, column = 0)
    for j in range(1,5): #Columns
        b = Entry(root)
        items.append(b)
        b.grid(row=i, column=j)
    rows.append(items)

def delete_row():
    for rowno, row in reversed(list(enumerate(rows))):
        if row[0].val.get() == 1:
            for i in row:
                i.destroy()
            rows.pop(rowno)


root = Tk()
bt = ttk.Button(root , text = 'Add Row', command = add_row)
bt.grid(row =0, column=0)


dl = ttk.Button(root , text = 'Delete Row', command = delete_row)
dl.grid(row =0, column=1)

v0 = StringVar()
e0 = Entry(root, textvariable = v0, state = 'readonly')
v0.set('Select')
e0.grid(row = 1, column = 0 )

v1 = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(root, textvariable = v1, state = 'readonly')
v1.set('Col1')
e1.grid(row = 1, column = 1 )

v2 = StringVar()
e2 = Entry(root, textvariable = v2, state = 'readonly')
v2.set('Col2')
e2.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

v3 = StringVar()
e3 = Entry(root, textvariable = v3, state = 'readonly')
v3.set('Col3')
e3.grid(row = 1, column = 3 )

v4 = StringVar()
e4 = Entry(root, textvariable = v4, state = 'readonly')
v4.set('Col4')
e4.grid(row = 1, column = 4 )

mainloop()
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot :)