# ttk.Checkbutton instate failing

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, tkinter.checkbutton

Using `ttk.Checkbutton.instate('selected')`  to get current state of a `checkbutton` gives me this error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 576, in instate
 self.tk.call(self._w, "instate", ' '.join(statespec)))_tkinter.TclError: Invalid state name s
```

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
def p(event):
    st = ck.state()
    if 'selected' in st:
        print ('got selected')
    if ck.instate('selected') :
        print('instate true')       
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200+300+200')
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

ck = ttk.Checkbutton(root,text = 'tryme')
ck.grid()
root.bind('<Return>',p)
root.mainloop()
```

The code should work now.  ck.instate('selected) gives error and appears to only see the first character of the argument

Comment: Please give us minimal reproducible code :) This example is not working - you did not defined `ck`. Provide the code and we can work from there :)

Comment: I believe you need to use `ck.instate(['selected'])` - a list of one or more state specifications, rather than a single state.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4236929/11101156

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `ck.state()` is returning what you think it is returning, and is the type that you expect?

Comment: jason harper comment is correct.  That fixed the problem.  Apparently instate expects a list, not a string.  Thank You